# Mac Thunderbolt-2 to Thunderbolt-3 large file transfer - error code -36

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-networking

I am trying to transfer files between 2 Macs, both running Sierra (10.12). I have enabled File Sharing on the source and successfully mounted the directory (Macintosh HD) from the client.

I was able to copy a few files. But as soon as it hit a large file (like 8MB). The file transfer fails:

`The Finder can't complete the operati
on because some data in "<filename>" can't be read or written.
(Error code -36)`

I can't figure out what went wrong. I am using a thunderbolt 3 to thunderbolt 2 adapter. Because the client Mac only has USB-C ports.